# Why do we see vertical lines when we close our eyes into slits?

Tags: optics, everyday-life, diffraction, vision

When we close our eyes into small slits and look at a light source we see vertical lines of light coming out. Why does this happen? Is it something to do with our eyelashes or is it because of diffraction(or any other phenomena)?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34222/2451 and links therein.