# Why do I see three 'beams' when I look to a distant light source at dark?

Tags: optics, visible-light, diffraction, vision

In the night, when I look at a distant light source (for example a street lamp a few hundred meters away) I do not simply see a spot but rather a spot which is surrounded by 'light beams'.

So instead of seeing the image on the left-hand side of the picture below I see the one on the right-hand side.

[image]

I know a similar effect also comes up by using camera lenses, even though I am not sure if the reason is exactly the same. Below, for example, is a picture with four 'beams' (Source: https://astromallorca.org/astrofotografias/dsc_0015/).

[image]

So, why do I see with my own eyes *three* beams whereas with a camera there appear to be more?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/34222/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic The effect described in your link is in fact similar. Nevertheless, I somehow doubt that both effects really have the same reason.

Comment: MinutePhysics has a good video on this topic. https://youtu.be/VVAKFJ8VVp4

Comment: Questions: Are the spikes as symmetrical as the drawing?  Do you see them without glasses?  Is it only a certain type of street-light?  Does it have to be cold out (ice crystals in the air)?

Comment: @aml 1.) The symmetry is quite perfect with both eyes open, and somehow weaker with one eye closed.. 2.) Yes, without glasses. 3.) Every kind of light. (Maybe not laser, but I do not regularly look into a laser) 4.) No, it also can be 30°C or more if you wish

Comment: The eye is a marvellous piece of evolution but it is not perfect. Many things can go wrong with it and cause strange problems with vision. Your optometrist will be able to inform you what it is about your eyes that causes this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to agweber's comment which pointed me [this Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VVAKFJ8VVp4&feature=youtu.be), I found the right solution: The cause of this effect are the so called *suture lines*.

A sketch of the lens and these lines can be found [here](https://www.atlasophthalmology.net/photo.jsf?node=3931&locale=en).

Another image plus an additional video is on this [webpage](https://timroot.com/lens-sutures-seen-in-the-eye-video/) (Better watch it only if you can stand medical pictures / videos)

There one can really see the Y-shaped suture lines. On that site, they also state that:

> ... sutures form because of how the lens epithelial cells proliferate during formation.

So, the effect is absolutely normal, and no deseases or abnormal defects are responsible for it.

Answer (score 19):

> **From physical point of view:**

- One reason is [**diffraction spike**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction_spike) by the mounts (support vanes) of optical reflector of reflecting telescope.  Four-fold mounts give four-fold diffraction pattern.  However, three-fold mounts give six-fold diffraction pattern since we can see intensity but not the phase of the diffraction pattern.  This can be reduced by [**other design**](https://www.astronomyclub.xyz/planetary-imaging/optical-quali.html).
- Photographers can add [**star effect filters**](https://hoyafilterusa.com/how-star-filters-work/) (which contains etched gridlines) on their cameras for shooting Christmas lights and so on.

  [image]

> **From medical point of view:**

- Another reason may be due to *astigmatism*, *glare* or *starbursting* of someone's eye.

  [image]
- See the link for the image [**here**](http://www.allaboutvision.com/visionsurgery/lasik_complication_1.htm) and vision simulations [**here**](https://visionsimulations.com/) and the causes of starbursting appears in [**this site**](http://delmarvisionandcosmetic.com/blog/b_74085_why_do_i_see_starbursts_around_lights_at_night.html).

Comment: Any idea about direct viewing (not through a camera?)

Comment: Because I've short-sight and astigmatism, my vision (with spectacles) at night is also spiky.

Comment: @NgChungTak Your answer and the wikipedia page you link are quite nice. But I cannot see where it is explained, that I - and I believe others too - see _three_ spikes instead of four. Unless you wanna say that my eyeballs are supported by three mounts!?

Comment: I'm not an optometrist or medical doctor to ensure whether is due to imperfection of your cornea or simply astigmatism.  It's unlikely due to diffraction (by optical instruments).  Perhaps, it's due to glare – light scattering due to dirty or impure optical materials in your eyes.  Would you like to refer the picture in this [**link**](http://www.blakebushfamilyeyecare.com/single-post/2016/02/10/WSYIWYG)?

Comment: @NgChungTak Have you  actually seen the effect that I describe in the OP with your own eyes?

Comment: I think starbursting might actually be the right hint

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71594/discussion-between-tho-re-and-ng-chung-tak).

Comment: Mild cataracts (is it identical in both eyes?) plus astigmatism would account for this easily.

Comment: @JimGarrison I think astigmatism is the most probable here.