# Strange Interference under monochromatic light

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, visible-light, interference, fluorescence

I'm coming to you with a strange physical/optical phenomenon I noticed today for which I'm looking for an explanation.  I can't seem to find references to this, and it was pretty surprising to see for the first time.

Background: I'm a photographer, and I am trying to experiment more with monochromatic light sources.  I hacked together a fixture for a relatively bright low pressure sodium (SOX 90 Watt) lamp, and it worked beautifully, producing a bright near-monochromatic yellow-orange light.  The first thing I did once I had it working was to take it into the bathroom.  There, I experienced the phenomenon: when I looked in the mirror, there was an interference pattern around my eyes in the reflection.  It looked a lot like Newton's Rings.  When I opened only my left eye, only my left eye's reflection had the rings around it.  When I tried to replicate this with a camera, I did not get the same effect, which leads me to believe it's something specific to the optics of the eye.

What's more, I have a pretty monochromatically red CFL in my bathroom, which I use successfully as a safe light.  I do not see this effect with the red light source.

Is this a well-known phenomenon that I just don't know the right words to search for?  Is this a function of wavelength?  I have also read that technically, low pressure sodium bulbs have two emission peaks, at 589.0nm and 589.6nm.  Does the gap between these cause some sort of constructive/destructive interference?

Thank you for your time.  As spooky as this was to discover, I am genuinely interested in how and why this was happening.

UPDATE:
I got my housemate to come in the bathroom with me, and he confirmed my observation.  What's more, we could see the rings in our own eyes, but not each other's eyes.

Comment: Just checking....you don't wear glasses do you?

Comment: Hello, no glasses or contacts.  My vision is generally pretty good.  I also see this effect in my reflection on panes of glass and several different mirrors.

Comment: Is it possible to take a photo of the reflection? If the same is in the image then it's not your eyes.

Comment: @josephh ,  As stated, taking a photo was my first reaction, but so far I have not been able to replicate the ringed effect.  Next time I have someone over, I will also see if they experience the same phenomenon.

Comment: OK, I didn't notice that part. It seems strange. Yeah, get a friend to confirm and then let us know. Good luck.

Comment: I started thinking about how you can get both vertical and horizontal diffraction patterns through both you eyelids and eye lashes respectively when you squint (this doesn’t account for your circular pattern though) and came across this answer (not duplicate) suggesting the liquid on you eye could bead up to produce a lense that forms a circular diffraction pattern. So I guess another question to ask that might rule out some possiblities is were you squinting or crying (or just welled up or had water in eyes from washing face or something)? https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/150941/305263

Comment: @mapplejacks The "rings around eyes in bathroom" interference effect was discussed on Physics Forums ([link](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/mirror-phenomenon-concentric-halos-around-eyes-in-a-foggy-bathroom.908472/)). "Rings around eyes in bathroom" somewhat resembles your observation. However, the mirror must be misty to see these rings, when using white light. As you did not mention a misty mirror, it may not explain your observation at all. Or perhaps the phenomenon is much more conspicuous when using monochromatic sodium light.

Comment: @jkien really interesting to see.  It definitely wasn't humid in the bathroom (it's an air-conditioned half bathroom in California, so the humidity is low and there isn't really a source of air moisture beyond the sink).  I have not looked into this in some time; maybe I'll have to dust off the old SOX light.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my poor english. My native language is French.

It is possible that what you saw were Quetelet fringes, or Newton diffusion rings.
They are discribed in this link : [Quetelet rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quetelet_rings) with another interesting link.

In general, in physical optics, the fringes only appear with well-worked glass slides, under certain lighting conditions. While these fringes can be observed with thick slides of any kind of glass. They are well described in old optical books and dew on the glass helps to see them, hence the interest of a bathroom !

They are also described in the book by Craig F. Bohren: "What Light Through Yonder Window Breaks"
Chapter 2 : interference patterns on garage door windows".

I can't do better than quote it :

> A particle on a window illuminated by a beam scatters toward the back
> surface of the window, and part of this scattered light is reflected
> to the observer.  But light from the incident beam also is reflected
> by the back-surface and illuminates the particle, which scatters some
> of this reflected light to the observer. Interference between these
> two beams with different histories -scattered by the particle, then
> reflected by the glass; or reflected by the glass, then scattered by
> the particles- is the origin of the beautiful colored fringes I saw.

Comment: It's an interesting hypothesis, and it was my first guess.  I'm somewhat familiar with Newton rings, as they can be an annoying issue with scanning film.  This bathroom did not have a shower in it (half bath) and the humidity in my house is very low, so no dew.  In my experience Newton rings generally are created at the boundary of two pieces of glass, though that doesn't seem to be the same situation as your quote.  But why would this only be the case under a monochromatic light source?

Answer (score 0):

It would be interesting to know the radius of the ring.

Here is an idea.

Presumably you were looking straight towards the mirror let's say from a distance $d$.

If there was constructive interference between the two wavelengths that you mentioned, if $n$ wavelengths of the longer wavelength light fitted in the distance $d$ and $n+1$ for the other wavelength, then

$$\frac{d}{\lambda_1} = n$$

$$\frac{d}{\lambda_2} = n+1$$

so

$$\frac{d}{\lambda_2} - \frac{d}{\lambda_1} = 1$$

$$d = \frac{\lambda_1\lambda_2}{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}$$

about 0.58mm

This distance is the smallest distance where the different wavelengths constructively interfere.

However it'll happen for any distance that is a multiple of the 0.58mm

If it happens for the straight ahead distance, from your eye to the mirror - doing a Pythagoras theorem for a right angled triangle from eye to mirror ($EM$) and a distance $r$ along the mirror at right angles to $EM$,  we can find another distance where  the constructive interference happens.

Taking $EM$ as 1 metre

$$1^2+ r^2 = 1.00058^2$$

A radius of 3.4cm

It's possible that the rings occur with a radius of about 3.4cm, the dark rings would be between the bright rings where the path difference was half a wavelength.

---

Update to include the radii for the first 10 maxima:

Using $d^2+ r^2 = (d + 0.00058n)^2$, where $n$ is the maxima number and $d$ is distance $EM$, now 0.5 metres

$r$ is approximately $$\sqrt{2dn \times 0.00058}$$ or $$\sqrt{5.8n}$$ in cm.

The radii, to the middle of each bright fringe, are

\begin{array}{r|r}
n & \text{       radius (mm)}\\
\hline
1 & 24 \\
2 & 34\\
3 & 42\\
4 & 48\\
5 & 54\\
6 & 59\\
7 & 64\\
8 & 68\\
9 & 72\\
10 & 76 
\end{array}

Comment: The wavelength is 589 nm so 1000 times smaller than what this answer uses.

Comment: @my2cts the answer uses 589 nm the 0.58mm is from the formula $d =\dots$

Comment: @JohnHunter , this is a good idea.  When I get a chance, I will attempt to measure this distance with a marker and ruler.

Comment: Ok I now see what you mean. However the two spectral lines are mutually incoherent and would not interfere.

Comment: @my2cts more data would be good.  Upon 'reflection' the Airy Disk idea might be the right one, with the pupil itself acting as the point-like source - (the circular aperture), that gives a radius of order mm.  Data about the ring size at different distances, maybe a sketch of the image and setup, and if it happens the same on a polished or different mirror would all help.

Comment: @JohnHunter, measuring was difficult since the rings are on a different plane of focus than the mirror, and blocking the mirror blocks the rings themselves.  But from what I was able to measure, I would say at 5 to 10 rings from the center, the pitch between the rings is 1-2mm, when I am about 0.5m from the mirror.  This effect works in several mirrors; tried it in my garage and it works in all my car mirrors and even the reflection of the car window.

Comment: [Here is a badly drawn  diagram](https://ibb.co/HFKDPBx)

Comment: Then it could be the Airy Disk idea, the first minimum happens at $\sin\theta = \frac{1.22\lambda}{d}$, with reflected light, out of the eye through the pupil, as the light source.  That would give about 1mm for the first minumum radius  - although not sure if enough light would enter the eye in the garage compared to a possibly white smaller bathroom...?

Comment: thanks for diagram - let's see what others say...

Comment: P.S. If you are able to vary the brightness of the light, by pointing the source different ways or partially covering it, the pupil would change size and you could see if there's a change of size of the observed pattern, that would test the pupil suggestion

Comment: P.P.S.  Answer now updated, it might match your diagram.  the low 1-2mm didn't seem to match at first, but for the rings 7 to 10, the separation is quite low (4mm).  What radii did you measured for rings 1 to 3?

Comment: It's hard to say exactly how many rings are in the center, since my eyes are relatively dark and most of the rings I see are on my brightly lit face.  Perhaps if I can get a white piece of paper and put a hole in it to look through I will have better luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127742/discussion-between-mapplejacks-and-john-hunter).

Answer (score 0):

You may be seeing an Airy disk. However i would expect rings about the light source rather than about the mirror image of your eyes. Could it be that the direct light does not reach your eyes but is covered?

Sodium light comes from two very close, narrow transitions of the sodium dimer, Na$_2$. It is strongly monochromatic, much more so than the red light you mention. I assume that you would have stated so if that is from a laser.

Your eye's pupil has a finite aperture of about 5 mm. This 1/8500 times the wavelength so the first interference minimum is expected at 0.04 degree. This is about a tenth of the angular diameter of the moon so it should be clearly perceptible.

It is possible that you use a much larger diaphragm when you take the photo so that the rings are much closer.

This analysis assumes a small pointlike light source.

Comment: This is interesting.  This effect worked both when I was backlit and side lit.  The light source is relatively large, about 50cm long and in a diffusing enclosure, which seems in many ways like the opposite of a pointlike source.

Yes, I suppose it is probably much more monochromatic than the red light.  The red only has to stay below a certain wavelength, and usually CFL phosphors have a pretty non-monochrome emission spectrum.

Comment: @ my2cts The pupil itself may act as the point-like source, so maybe this proposal is ok